Esp32 Cam + Display TFT (Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited))
I'm trying to do facial recognition using the CameraWebServer example from esp32 cam and I also integrated a display to show the camera image.
The code compiles and everything, but when I try to do facial recognition, it returns the following error:
Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC : 0x40140b56 PS : 0x00060330 A0 : 0x800d34bc A1 : 0x3ffdf130
A2 : 0x00000000 A3 : 0x3ffc5928 A4 : 0x00000002 A5 : 0x3ffdf130
A6 : 0x00000000 A7 : 0x3ffde640 A8 : 0x00000a1c A9 : 0x3ffdf1b4
A10 : 0x00000008 A11 : 0x00000001 A12 : 0x00000005 A13 : 0x00000020
A14: 0x00000020 A15: 0x00000000 SAR: 0x0000001f EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x00000010 LBEG: 0x4000c46c LEND: 0x4000c477 LCOUNT: 0x00000000
Backtrace: 0x40140b56:0x3ffdf130 0x400d34b9:0x3ffdf150 0x40140bc5:0x3ffdf190 0x4013e5be:0x3ffdf250 0x4013e6cd:0x3ffdf280 0x400d20f4:0x3ffdf2a0 0x400e73e5:0x3ffdf450 0x400e7a39:0x3ffdf480 0x400e7b15:0x3ffdf510 0x400e7f18:0x3ffdf530 0x400e6776:0x3ffdf550 0x400e67c7:0x3ffdf590 0x4008de55:0x3ffdf5b0
My code:
#include "esp_camera.h"
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#include "camera_pins.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <TJpg_Decoder.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>

const char* ssid = "Elis Regina";
const char* password = "37112837";

void startCameraServer();

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();

bool tft_output(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t* bitmap) {
  // Stop further decoding as image is running off bottom of screen
  if (y >= tft.height()) return 0;

  // This function will clip the image block rendering automatically at the TFT boundaries
  tft.pushImage(x, y, w, h, bitmap);

  // This might work instead if you adapt the sketch to use the Adafruit_GFX library
  // tft.drawRGBBitmap(x, y, bitmap, w, h);

  // Return 1 to decode next block
  return 1;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println();

   // Initialise the TFT
  Serial.println("INIT DISPLAY");

  tft.begin();
  tft.setRotation(3);
  tft.setTextColor(0xFFFF, 0x0000);
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);

  TJpgDec.setJpgScale(1);
  TJpgDec.setSwapBytes(true);
  TJpgDec.setCallback(tft_output);

  Serial.println("INIT CAMERA");

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_QVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  startCameraServer();

  Serial.print("Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");
}


camera_fb_t* capture() {
  camera_fb_t* fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  return fb;
}

void showingImage() {
  camera_fb_t* fb = capture();
  if (!fb || fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    return;
  } else {
    TJpgDec.drawJpg(0, 0, (const uint8_t*)fb->buf, fb->len);
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  showingImage();
  
}

I don't know how to solve this, I've looked for several solutions, but nothing
Backtrace decoded
PC: 0x40140af6: _jpg_read at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/components/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c line 65
EXCVADDR: 0x00000010

Decoding stack results
0x40140af6: _jpg_read at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/components/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c line 65
0x400d3471: jd_prepare at C:\Users\bruno\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TJpg_Decoder\src\tjpgd.c line 1777
0x40140b65: esp_jpg_decode at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/components/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c line 91
0x4013e55e: jpg2rgb888 at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/components/esp32-camera/conversions/to_bmp.c line 127
0x4013e66d: fmt2rgb888 at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/components/esp32-camera/conversions/to_bmp.c line 177
0x400d2398: stream_handler(httpd_req_t*) at C:\Users\bruno\Desktop\Funcionando_10-12/app_httpd.cpp line 366
0x400e7385: httpd_uri at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server/src/httpd_uri.c line 218
0x400e79d9: httpd_parse_req at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server/src/httpd_parse.c line 594
0x400e7ab5: httpd_req_new at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server/src/httpd_parse.c line 664
0x400e7eb8: httpd_sess_process at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server/src/httpd_sess.c line 298
0x400e6716: httpd_server at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server/src/httpd_main.c line 197
0x400e6767: httpd_thread at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server/src/httpd_main.c line 227
0x4008de55: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/port.c line 143


Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.
